# compile zmq on sh4 CPU and occurs referenced by DSO error

Tags: gcc, makefile, zeromq, automake

I found if I add -shared, It will solve the make problem, but, I don't know where to modify the Makefile. I've tried LDFLAGS,CXXFLAGS in Makefile https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5453234 , it can not work.

```
[dlin@h perf]$ make V=1
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -O2 -pipe -shared  -shared  -o local_lat local_lat.o ../src/libzmq.la -lrt -lpthread -shared
libtool: link: g++ -O2 -pipe -o .libs/local_lat local_lat.o  ../src/.libs/libzmq.so -lrt -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/local_lat: hidden symbol `__sync_fetch_and_add_2' in /usr/lib/gcc/sh4-linux/4.2.4/libgcc.a(linux-atomic.o) is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [local_lat] Error 1
[dlin@h perf]$ g++ -O2 -pipe -o .libs/local_lat local_lat.o  ../src/.libs/libzmq.so -lrt -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/local_lat: hidden symbol `__sync_fetch_and_add_2' in /usr/lib/gcc/sh4-linux/4.2.4/libgcc.a(linux-atomic.o) is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
[dlin@h perf]$ g++ -O2 -pipe -o .libs/local_lat local_lat.o  ../src/.libs/libzmq.so -lrt -lpthread -shared
```

The -shared option workable on manual write at the last command, but how to put in Makefile?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely a `-shared` delays the error till runtime, it would appear GCC for *SuperH* does not have full atomic support.  The options are thus to encode the required atomics or use the mutex fallback.

You can force use of a mutex by patching `configure.ac` with the following:

```
sh-* | sh[34]*-*)
    AC_DEFINE(ZMQ_FORCE_MUTEXES, 1, [Force to use mutexes])
    ;;
```

Which is not going to be significantly worse than native support as *SuperH* hardware only offers test-and-set on a byte via the `tas.b` op.  A mutex op could be replaced with the following compare-and-swap:

```
static unsigned char sh_critical_section = 0;

inline static void sh_enter_critical_section (void)
{
  unsigned int oldval;   
  do
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("tas.b @%1; movt %0"
              : "=r" (oldval)
              : "r" (&sh_critical_section)
              : "t", "memory");
  while (oldval == 0);
}

inline static void sh_leave_critical_section (void)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ (" " ::: "memory");
  sh_critical_section= 0;
}
```

Thus the following modifications could be made:

```
#elif defined ZMQ_ATOMIC_COUNTER_SH
            sh_enter_critical_section ();
            old_value = value;
            value += increment_;
            sh_leave_critical_section ();    
#elif defined ZMQ_ATOMIC_COUNTER_MUTEX
            sync.lock ();
            old_value = value;
            value += increment_;
            sync.unlock ();
#else
```

Which is redundant as the functionality is the same as the mutex implementation, so one could move the `tas.b` op to the `mutex_t` implementation but would need to introduce a global variable for the lock, you would gain hardly anything over the *pthread* implementation of a mutex.

Run a performance test to see if there is any measurable performance improvement or even degradation and submit a pull request upstream for others to enjoy!

Comment: You are so power, how to detect the problem is caused by gcc without sh4 support. Why not `unsigned int oldval` defined as `unsigned char`?

Comment: To quick check just try to use mutex, I've made a patch, https://gist.github.com/5458192, but it can not work, still show the same error message.  I'm not familiar with automake.

Comment: @DanielYCLin you need to run `autogen.sh` to recreate the `configure` file from `configure.ac`.  You can always `grep sh- configure` to confirm it applied.

Comment: my build script[PKGBUILD](https://gist.github.com/5469088),[configure.in](https://gist.github.com/5469047) ,and the [error log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5605493) and ./configure contains the sh- patch